# Uncapacited Facility location covering

Tags: python, pulp

I am trying to solve this problem using pulp :

[image: Set covering problem]

This is my code, There is a problem, because the result should be to only keep the second Location :

```
    # Import PuLP modeler functions
        from pulp import *
        
        # Set of locations J
        Locations = ["A", "B","C"]

        # Set of demands I
        Demands = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
        
        #  Set of distances ij
        dt = [  # Demands I
            # 1 2 3 4 5
            [2, 23, 30, 54, 1],  # A   Locations J
            [3, 1, 2, 2, 3],  # B
            [50,65,80,90,100] # C distances are very long
        ]
        
        # Max value to get covered
        s = 5
        
        # Theses binaries values should be generated by code from the dt array ... I write it down directly for simplification. 
        # Demand I is served by location J If distance is <= 5 (  0 = KO , 1 = OK)
        covered = [
            [1,0,0,0,1],
            [1,1,1,1,1] # This shows that we only need Location B , not A
            [0,0,0,0,0] # This shows we can't use Location C, it's too far
        ]
        
        # Creates the 'prob' variable to contain the problem data
        prob = LpProblem("Set covering", LpMinimize)
        
        # # Problem variables 
        J = LpVariable.dicts("location", Locations, cat='Binary')
        
        # The distance data is made into a dictionary
        distances = makeDict([Locations, Demands], covered, 0)
        
        # The objective function 
        # Minimize J, which is the number of locations
        prob += lpSum(J["A"]+J["B"]+J["C"])  
        
        # The constraint
        # Is it covered or not ?
        for w in Locations:
            for b in Demands:   
                if(distances[w][b] > 0): 
                    prob += int(distances[w][b]) * J[w]  >= 1
        
        # Or eventually this instead : 
        #for w in Locations:
        #  prob += (lpSum([distances[w][b] * J[w] for b in Demands]) >= 1)

        # or that :
        # prob += 1 * J["A"] >= 1
        # prob += 1 * J["A"] >= 1
        # prob += 1 * J["B"] >= 1
        # prob += 1 * J["B"] >= 1
        # prob += 1 * J["B"] >= 1
        # prob += 1 * J["B"] >= 1
        # prob += 1 * J["B"] >= 1

        
        # The problem data is written to an .lp file
        prob.writeLP("SetCovering.lp")
        
        # The problem is solved using PuLP's choice of Solver
        prob.solve()
        
        # The status of the solution is printed to the screen
        print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])
        
        # Each of the variables is printed with it's resolved optimum value
        for v in prob.variables():
            print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
        
        # The optimised objective function value is printed to the screen
        print("Total Locations  = ", value(prob.objective))
        
        # Show constraints
        constraints = prob.constraints
        print(constraints)
        
        



#Status: Optimal
#location_A = 1.0
#location_B = 1.0
#location_C = 0.0
#Total Locations  =  2.0
```

The result should be :

```
location_A = 0.0
location_B = 1.0
location_C = 0.0
```

because location B covers all of our needs.

I wonder where is the problem, there is the maths code , I hope I wrote enough:

[image: maths codes]

Thanks , it's nice if you have a solution, I have also tried lpSum with no luck

Edit : Modified the code a few, you can see 'optimal solution', but It's not the solution I want + Added a "Location_C"

**EDIT :** This is my new code, added a secondary continuous pulp dict for arcs(links) generation (ser_customer) . The solver should only pick Fac-2 in this case, because it's near all of the customers, and other facilities are way too far:

```
# Lists (sets / Array) of Customers and Facilities
Customer = [1,2,3,4,5]
Facility = ['Fac-1', 'Fac-2', 'Fac-3']

# Dictionary of distances in kms
distance = {'Fac-1' : {1 : 54, 2 : 76, 3 : 5, 4 : 76, 5 : 76},
            'Fac-2' : {1 : 1, 2 : 3, 3 : 1, 4 : 8, 5 : 1},
            'Fac-3' : {1 : 45, 2 : 23, 3 : 54, 4 : 87, 5 : 88}
            }

# Setting the Problem
prob = LpProblem("pb", LpMinimize)

# Defining our Decision Variables
use_facility = LpVariable.dicts("Use Facility", Facility, 0, 1, LpBinary)
ser_customer = LpVariable.dicts("Service", [(i,j) for i in Customer for j in Facility], 0)

# Setting the Objective Function = Minimize amount of facilities and arcs
prob += lpSum(use_facility['Fac-1']+use_facility['Fac-2']+use_facility['Fac-3']) + lpSum(distance[j][i]*ser_customer[(i,j)] for j in Facility for i in Customer)

# Constraints,At least 1 arc must exist between facilities and customers
for i in Customer:
      prob += lpSum(ser_customer[(i,j)] for j in Facility) >= 1

prob.solve()

# Print the solution of Decision Variables
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)

# Print the solution of Binary Decision Variables
Tolerance = 0.0001
for j in Facility:
    if use_facility[j].varValue > Tolerance:
        print("Establish Facility at site = ", j)
```

The result seems to show good arcs(links), but there is no facility selection, I wonder if somebody have any idea, is there any way to force use_facility[index] to be > 0 , Is adding arcs decisions variables a good idea ? I have tried to moove the arcs as a constraint too instead of being into the objective function, with no luck. :

```
Service_(1,_'Fac_1') = 0.0
Service_(1,_'Fac_2') = 1.0
Service_(1,_'Fac_3') = 0.0
Service_(2,_'Fac_1') = 0.0
Service_(2,_'Fac_2') = 1.0
Service_(2,_'Fac_3') = 0.0
Service_(3,_'Fac_1') = 0.0
Service_(3,_'Fac_2') = 1.0
Service_(3,_'Fac_3') = 0.0
Service_(4,_'Fac_1') = 0.0
Service_(4,_'Fac_2') = 1.0
Service_(4,_'Fac_3') = 0.0
Service_(5,_'Fac_1') = 0.0
Service_(5,_'Fac_2') = 1.0
Service_(5,_'Fac_3') = 0.0
Use_Facility_Fac_1 = 0.0
Use_Facility_Fac_2 = 0.0
Use_Facility_Fac_3 = 0.0
```

I also have tried the AirSquid solution, ,I think I maybe miss sources decisions variables who should be minimized but don' t know how to do, I guess covered are arcs (links), anyway It is a good exercise, harder than a simple product mix, hi hi :

```
 prob = LpProblem('source minimzer', LpMinimize)
dist_limit = 5
sources = ['A', 'B','C']            # the source locations
# note this is zero-indexed to work with the list indexes in dist dictionary...
destinations = list(range(5))   # the demand locations 0, 1, 2, 3, 4   
dist = {    'A': [2, 23, 30, 54, 1],
            'B': [3, 1, 2, 2, 3],
            'C':[24,54,12,56,76]}

covered = LpVariable.dicts('covered', [(s, d) for s in sources for d in destinations], cat='Binary')

# The objective function 
# Minimize  the number of sources
prob += lpSum(covered[s, d]) 

# set up constraint to limit covered if the destination is "reachable"
for s in sources:
    for d in destinations:
        prob += covered[s, d] * dist[s][d] <= dist_limit


# add one more constraint to make sure that every destination is "covered"...

# The problem is solved using PuLP's choice of Solver
prob.solve()

# The status of the solution is printed to the screen
print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])

# The optimised objective function value is printed to the screen
print("Location Selection = ", prob.objective)
```

The solution displayed, while it should print "B" :

```
Status: Optimal
Total Locations  =  covered_('C',_4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track!  A couple things will help...

First, you overlooked a *key* piece of information in your output in that the solver says your formulation is INFEASIBLE!

```
Status: Infeasible
```

So whatever came out in the variables is gibberish and you must figure that part out first.

So, why is it infeasible?  Take a look at your constraint.  You are trying to *force* the impossible if your distance value is zero this *cannot* be true:

```
prob += int(distances[w][b]) * J[w]  >= 1
```

So, you need to reformulate!  You are missing a concept here.  You actually need 2 constraints for this problem.

1. You need to constrain the selection of a source-destination if the route is too long
2. You need to enforce that every destination is covered.

You also need a double-indexed decision variable.  Why?  Well, lets say that source 'A' covers destination 1, 2; and 'B' covers 2, 3, 4, 5....  You will be able to know that all the destinations are "covered" with one variable, but you will not know which sources were used, so you need to keep track of both to get the full picture.

Here is a start, along with a couple edits.  I'd suggest the variable names `source` and `destination` as that is kinda standard.  You do not have a specific `demand` in this particular problem, just the need for a connection.  You might also want to use dictionaries more than nested lists, I think it is clearer.  Below is an example start with the first constraint.  Note the trick here in limiting the covered variable.  If the distance is less than the limit, `s`, then this constraint is satisfiable.  For instance, if the distance is 3:

```
3 * 1 <= s
```

Anyhow, here is a recommended start.  The other constraint is not implemented.  You will need to sum across all the sources to ensure the destination is "covered".  Comment back if your are stuck.

```
prob = LpProblem('source minimzer', LpMinimize)
dist_limit = 5
sources = ['A', 'B']            # the source locations
# note this is zero-indexed to work with the list indexes in dist dictionary...
destinations = list(range(5))   # the demand locations 0, 1, 2, 3, 4   
dist = {    'A': [2, 23, 30, 54, 1],
            'B': [3, 1, 2, 2, 3]}

covered = LpVariable.dicts('covered', [(s, d) for s in sources for d in destinations], cat='Binary')
# set up constraint to limit covered if the destination is "reachable"
for s in sources:
    for d in destinations:
        prob += covered[s, d] * dist[s][d] <= dist_limit

# add one more constraint to make sure that every destination is "covered"...
```

Comment: How will be the objective function ?

Comment: You will probably need to introduce another variable that just counts the number of supply sources used and minimize that.  Give it a whirl.

Comment: I will also try using this example and remove costs, and unecessary variables : https://github.com/hakeemrehman/Python-PuLP-/blob/master/Capacitated%20Facility%20Location%20Problem.ipynb

Comment: I am scared because I have tried to copy the mathematical model the most as possible, I thought It was ok, I suppose that a decision var dict is kind of missing. I am scary about the future because I thought that copying the mathematical model was simple as that.. Thanks a lot, I will try it again today

Comment: Can you or another person please confirm the mathematical model is ok ? Thanks

Comment: OK.  Just looked at the solution presented.  It works fine too.  It is very close to your original.  You were just missing the sum over `J` in your constraint.  By pre-computing the `D` matrix as you were doing, the problem gets a little smaller, but at the end of it, you don't know which service station is servicing the locations, but that doesn't seem important in this problem.

Comment: Hi, how can I add the sum over J, please, tx

Comment: I have some kind of results using his code https://github.com/hakeemrehman/Python-PuLP-/blob/master/Capacitated%20Facility%20Location%20Problem.ipynb and settings all demands to 1 : Demand = {1 : 1, 2 : 1, 3 : 1, 4 : 1, 5 : 1} , But still Have to set the Minimum value for a customer to be covered

Comment: There is no objective function in your code