# Python Pulp: Optimise while limiting element frequency between groups

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I am trying to optimise a problem with several constraints, where elements (e.g. person) are duplicated between groups and I need to select the correct elements such that the total **groups scores** are maximised.

1. I can only select an element (e.g person) **1 time**.
2. A person can be initially assigned to multiple groups
3. Each group can only consist of **2 people**
4. Each person has a difference score for each group they are initially assigned to

I have created a toy example below:

```
# example data
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'person': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 1, 4, 7],
    'score': [3, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.7, 0.8, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 2, 1.1]
})


prob = pulp.LpProblem("group_scores", sense=pulp.LpMaximize)

group = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("group", data['group'], cat=pulp.LpBinary)
person = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("group", data['person'].unique(), cat=pulp.LpBinary)

# CONSTRAINTS
# set group size
prob += pulp.lpSum(group) == 2

# 1 person cannot be seletced more than once
for p in person:
    prob += pulp.lpSum(p) <= 1

# objective is to maximise score per group and overall
# TODO: I have a strong feeling this objective function is incorrect
prob += pulp.lpSum([person[p] * data[data['person'] == p]['score'].values[0] for p in person])

prob.solve()

results = []
for v in prob.variables():
    results.append({
        'group': v.name.split('group_')[1], 'selected': True if v.varValue else False
    })
results = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

Comment: Here's a clue to help:  How will you know which group a person was selected from?  You almost certainly need to consider all (legal) combinations of person, group.  So, I'd expect that you will need a double-indexed variable like `select[person, group]`.  After that your other constraints should fall into place more easily, along with the scoring.

Comment: @AirSquid thank you for the clue however I do not understand what you mean by double-indexed variable, further, I am not clear on how I would utilise such a variable.

Comment: Here is an example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72803291/uncapacited-facility-location-covering/72804002#72804002